# Decoding a Base 64 Image url - MVC 4 Razor (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

How do I get the Image Path from below base 64 string?

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(_model.Image_Array[i]);
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Product/"), fileName);
                file[i].SaveAs(path);
```

But it is throwing up below error:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Comment: The string isn't a path. It's the actual image **data** encoded in base64

Comment: So, how do I get the actual file path?

Comment: You don't. Unless you want to compare the image with all images in a specific directory.

Comment: So, how do I save the image?